# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zero_shot_re'

Tags: pip, modulenotfounderror, relation-extraction

I try to install `$ pip install zero-shot-re` however I got the error:

```
(biomedical-knowledge-graph-venv) C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\biomedical-knowledge-graph-nlp>pip install zero-shot-re
Collecting zero-shot-re
  Using cached zero_shot_re-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.1 (from zero-shot-re)
  Using cached numpy-1.19.1.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [134 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
      <string>:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py:73: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        required_version = LooseVersion('0.29.21')
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py:75: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        if LooseVersion(cython_version) < required_version:
      performance hint: _common.pyx:275:19: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:299:19: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:322:50: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:426:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:465:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:509:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:592:36: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:596:36: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:600:36: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:604:36: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:638:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:675:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:712:63: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:754:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:785:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:903:40: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:907:40: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:911:41: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:916:40: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:920:41: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:924:38: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:960:31: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _common.pyx:1002:32: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.

      performance hint: _generator.pyx:707:41: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
          2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.
      performance hint: _generator.pyx:736:45: Exception check will always require the GIL to be acquired. Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
          2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              for i in range(1, RK_STATE_LEN):
                  self.rng_state.key[i] = val[i]
              self.rng_state.pos = i

              self._bitgen.state = &self.rng_state
              self._bitgen.next_uint64 = &mt19937_uint64
                                         ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      _mt19937.pyx:138:35: Cannot assign type 'uint64_t (*)(void *) except? -1 nogil' to 'uint64_t (*)(void *) noexcept nogil'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'uint64_t (void *) except? -1 nogil'.
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py", line 235, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py", line 231, in main
          find_process_files(root_dir)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py", line 222, in find_process_files
          process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py", line 188, in process
          processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-axs3irod\numpy_9882ca35e3334eb09c9f2615a114ebea\tools\cythonize.py", line 77, in process_pyx
          subprocess.check_call(
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\biomedical-knowledge-graph-nlp\\biomedical-knowledge-graph-venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'cython', '-3', '--fast-fail', '-o', '_mt19937.c', '_mt19937.pyx']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Cythonizing sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\biomedical-knowledge-graph-nlp\biomedical-knowledge-graph-venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\biomedical-knowledge-graph-nlp\biomedical-knowledge-graph-venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\biomedical-knowledge-graph-nlp\biomedical-knowledge-graph-venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k0s9f8gt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 396, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k0s9f8gt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-k0s9f8gt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 499, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 479, in setup_package
        File "<string>", line 274, in generate_cython
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I want to install `zero_shot_re` to run my code in python:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from zero_shot_re import RelTaggerModel, RelationExtractor

model = RelTaggerModel.from_pretrained("fractalego/fewrel-zero-shot")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")
relations = ['associated', 'interacts']
extractor = RelationExtractor(model, tokenizer, relations)
```

This code use for relation extraction, and I am trying to run this google colab notebook.
[text](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tomasonjo/blogs/blob/master/bionlp/bioNLP2graph.ipynb#scrollTo=NAkdhz5xCUGY)

Anybody can help me, thanks alot.

I tried:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

`pip install --upgrade cython`

`pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel`

`pip install --no-cache-dir -v numpy==1.19.1`

However I still stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem comes from the numpy version and the zero-shot-re package.

Since I use Python 3.10 with the default numpy version and the zero-shot-re package does not fit.

Then I used Python 3.7 and installed numpy==1.19.1, this numpy version is adequate with the python version and the zero-shot-re package.